# How do I test the difference between male and female in this dataset? (Paired Wilcoxon??)

Tags: statistical-significance

In my study I want to test if certain cities were predominantly visited for holidays or for work (see boxplot below). That means I want to know if there is a difference between the grey box and the white box for each group (City). I have about 20 persons in my study. Some were traveling a lot. That is why for the boxplot I chose 'Proportion of visits' as the y-axis. Can I used a paired Wilcoxon test for each city (paired for each individual and using the number of counts) or is that wrong?

I am totally unsure. Help would be very appreciated.

[image]